# Google API error with OSGb

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, osgi

I am building an application that use Google API and OSGI, I use below maven to download library:

```
compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '1.9.54'
```

But when I deploy project into server, than OSGI tell that some unsolvable package like:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.annotations
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.logging
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.html
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.math
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.parameterset
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common
com.google.httputil
```

I find them by google but I did not see any library like that. Do you have any idea?

Comment: "repackaged" in the package name hints that these packages are likely embedded inside the appengine jar.

Comment: I am a beginner with Java and OSGI so can you please tell more detail?

Comment: And how about other google libraries like:

com.google.inject

com.google.inject.util

com.google.net.base

com.google.httputil